# Convert Mysqli query without using MYSQLND?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

I don't have the mysqlnd driver on my shared server.

How do I write this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$servers = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Without having the mysqlnd driver?

Comment: How do you currently connect to your server database?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$servers = array();
$result = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $servers[] = $row;
}
```

^^^ That worked!